# Unexpected null value when trying to fetch data from local json file in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

```
Future<List<User>> allUsers() async {

    var response = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/text_file.json");

    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response);

    if (jsonData.isNotEmpty) {
      return userFromJson(jsonData);
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: the statement  jsonData.isNotEmpty will throw error when jsonData is null.

Answer (score 0):

First add the file in pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/text_file.json
```

Then use below code to read the json file:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
Future<void> loadAsset(BuildContext context) async {
  final jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
      .loadString('assets/text_file.json');
  final dynamic jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
 //print(jsonMap['key']);

}
```